# A question about regular signed or complex Borel measure under LRN decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\nu$ is a regular signed or complex Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$, *m* is the Lebesgue measure on the class of Borel sets $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R^n}$ and the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition of $\nu$ is $d\nu=d\lambda+fdm$ where *f* is an extended *m*-integrable function when $\nu$ is a signed measure or $\in L^1(m)$ when $\nu$ is a complex measure and $\lambda\bot m$. Prove that $d|\nu|=d|\lambda|+|f|dm$ where the notation $|\bullet|$ represents total variation.

PS: A Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is regular if $\nu(K)<\infty$ for every compact *K*. From this definition we have $\nu(E)=\inf \{\nu(U)|U{\;\rm{ open},}U\supseteq E\}$. A signed or complex Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$ is regular if $|\nu|$ is regular.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this something you have seen in a textbook and are trying to work out? or a generalization of something you have seen?

Comment: As phrased, this does not really look appropriate for MO; but perhaps I am failing to notice some subtlety here...

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Does my question hurt you?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: No, you are not.

Comment: He means it looks like a homework-type problem (which is inappropriate here) and not a research-type problem (which is appropriate here).

Comment: @Gerald In case your comment is directed at mine, please reread what I wrote.

Comment: It seems I have to say something here. We know that for two signed or complex measures $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$, we always have $|\nu_1+\nu_2|\leq|\nu_1|+|\nu_2|$. But I want to know under what condition can the equality $|\nu_1+\nu_2|=|\nu_1|+|\nu_2|$, in particular $d|\nu|=d|\lambda|+|f|dm$ in the LRN decomposition, hold. I hold a firm view before posting this thread that the regularity of $\nu$ is the reason that causes the equality but I failed to prove it, so I ask with the hope that someone can prove the equality from regularity. Since I can not see any relation between ... (to be continued)

Comment: Choi' comments and my question, and I think I did not offend him/her (actually I sensed some smell of arrogance which really offend me, maybe I am a little bit too sensitive), I do not understand these two comments.


Comment: And I also want to say something about what happend about the answer. I remember I up-voted the answer after I accepted it, but this number is 0 now. According to my limit understanding of rules of this website, this is because someone down-voted it. I was very surprised to see it. I up-vote this answer because first it proves the equality in my question, second because it points out that the equality is due to the singularity, but not the regularity as I had thought. I really do not understand why someone down-voted it. ... (to be continued)

Comment: I want to say to him/her: If you can not answer, please respect people who can answer. I know this comment is irrelative to my mathematical question but I have to say, because if I do not support people who help me, who will help me later?

Comment: @zzzhhh: I am sorry if you perceive me as being arrogant, but I do not see MO as a place where I carry out my duties as a teacher, and **I do not see MO as a substitute for teaching**. When I say the question is not appropriate, I do not mean you should find it easy; I mean that it is something at the level of an exercise during one's studies, and not really -- to use Gerald Edgar's phrasing -- a "research-type problem."

Comment: @Didier: I think Gerald's comment was in response to the original poster, and not to you

Comment: It should also be said that the question is not phrased as "I am trying to understand why this works; am I correct in thinking that regularity plays an important part in the proof of the result?" It was phrased as "Prove that..." and I think people on this site could be justified in thinking "why should I (try to) prove that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu\bot\lambda$, then $|\nu+\lambda|=|\nu|+|\lambda|$